# Creating Datadog alerts for when the percentage difference between two custom metrics goes over a specified percentage threshold

Tags: triggers, threshold, alerts, datadog

My current situation is that I have two different data feeds (Feed A & Feed B) and I have created custom metrics for both feeds:

- Metric of Order counts from Feed A
- Metric Order counts from Feed B

Next steps is to create alert monitoring for the agreed upon threshold of difference between the two metrics. Say we have agreed that it is acceptable for Order Counts from Feed A to be within ~5% of Order Counts from Feed B. How can I go about creating that threshold and comparison between the two metrics that I have already developed in Datadog?

I would like to send alerts to myself when the % difference between the two data feeds is > 5 % for a daily validation.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to get this if you...

1. Start creating a metric type monitor
2. To the far right of the metric definition, select "advanced"
3. Select "Add Query"
4. Input your metrics
5. In the field called "Express these queries as:", input `(a-b)/b` or some such
6. Trigger when the metric is `above or equal to` the threshold `in total` during the last `24 hours`
7. Set Alert threshold >= `0.05`

If you start having trouble as you start setting it up, you may want to reach out to support@datadoghq.com to get their assistance.